# Clear all data on page when navigated to other view? Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation

In my ionic angular application, I have a page where I filled in some information and then I navigate to other page. Now the problem is that when I visit this page via some other path that previously filled data remains there.
I need whenever I am done with submitting data and just about to navigate, the page should not contain any previous data, it should be a fresh page each time

Comment: Please post your code with what you have already tried.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

By default ionic caches the pages to serve better performance. To have a fresh page every time, you could clear all input fields on the `ionViewWillEnter` lifecycle hook.
If you are using `ngModel` then you can clear it out as following:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
 this.inputField = '';
}
```

or you can use Some sort of looping mechanism to clear all input fields.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-raraak?file=pages/home/home.ts